# What IP address will a jboss app use when there are multiple IPs bound to a network interface

Tags: networking, jboss, ip, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

What IP address will a app running in jboss use when there are multiple IPs bound to a network interface on the server running the jboss?

is there a way to force it to use a particular IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints of application services running on a specific JBoss 7.x instance are bound to the ports defined in this instances `socket-binding-group` in your `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml` configuration file.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

These sockets are defined accordingly on named interface (usually `public` for application services), that can be configured in various ways. An `interface` configuration may include the name of the NIC and the IP address which is what you requested:

```
<interfaces>
    ... other definitions

    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="10.11.12.13"/>
        <nic name="eth0" />
    </interface>       
</interfaces>
```

Have a look at the [JBoss 7 configuration documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/General+configuration+concepts) (section *Interfaces*) for more options.

Good luck!